# TextView and Button is hidden behind ImageView

Tags: android, mobile

When I put multiple TextViews in design under the Image they appear behind it, and not under as I want [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhwso.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/book_1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I put Image under the textView in Component Tree, it appers OK [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Psf.png)

Comment: What do really want to design? Do you want  to have the image view a the Top and other component below it? If so, then the LinearLayout with its orientation to Vertical must work.

Comment: Well, it's already vertical

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this one below too:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="TextView4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="TextView5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="TextView6"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```